# Remove htop grey filler

Tags: htop

I recently started to notice grey "filler" in some of my servers when viewing htop as shown in the image below.

[image]

Does anybody know how to get rid fo this and go back to "normal" like below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `htop` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the setup. Then select `Colors` on the left column and choose another theme.

If that doesn't work for you, you probably need to change the colors for the Terminal color scheme you are currently using.

Comment: Setting it to "Broken Gray" resolves the issue for me and makes it look close enough to the original. I had no idea this option was here. Thanks!